# Elixir / Horde : DynamicSupervisor.start_child() gets blocked with a cryptic warning message

Tags: elixir

I'm using Elixir 1.10.1 with Horde 0.8.3 as a backend API for a mobile and web app. Basically, a user is represented by a `UserAgent`, UA for short, (implemented with a `GenServer`) which is unique across the cluster and which exists as long as there is at least one live connection from client application. Clients can connect many times (phone, tablet, web, from home, from work, etc); each connection is represented by a `ConnectionAgent`, CA for short, which is unique. CA are alive as long as the user didn't logout or the session didn't expire. Basically, I only have a unique UA but I can have several CA.

The `login` procedure takes three steps

1. Upon reception of the HTTP login request (JSON content), the `login()` controller is called. After some checks it calls `Horde.DynamicSupervisor.start_child(...)` to create and register a new CA.
2. The supervisor calls `ConnectionAgent.start_link()` is called which in turn calls `GenServer.start_link()` with appropriate parameters and eventually the `ConnectionAgent.init()` is called
3. The CA is supposed either to create a new UA or to connect to the  existing one  so it calls `Horde.DynamicSupervisor.start_child(...)

A that moment, the program freezes and I get the following warning messages forever in the console and  I definitely don't know what to with them:

```
[warn] Exit while fetching metrics from AlaaarmApi.DSup.
Skip poll action. Reason: {:timeout, {GenServer, :call, [AlaaarmApi.DSup, :get_telemetry, 5000]}}.
```

I'm just stuck so any hint would be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked for current and past issues in the Horde library?

It seems to be an issue related with Horde. It was at least a known issue in Horde 0.8.2 which was supposed to be solved in 0.8.3 (see [here](https://github.com/derekkraan/horde/issues/220#issuecomment-729036446) and [here too](https://github.com/derekkraan/horde/issues/211)).

Open an issue in GitHub and the maintainers/users will surely help you!

Comment: No I didn't but as per your advice I did and I added comment to the case (that was closed). The maintainer identified the issue as a deadlock and [adviced to create a second supervisor](https://github.com/derekkraan/horde/issues/211#issuecomment-797941371). This actually solved the issue.